# Converting Filtered graph into regular Graph(adjacency list) in boost

Tags: boost, graph

I am using boost graph library for solving a network graph problem. I have a situation where I need to convert the filtered graph back to regular(adjacency list). I am not sure how I can copy a filtered graph into regular graph. Can anybody tell me how I can actually convert the filtered graph back to regular graph.

The reason I want to convert back is because, I need to generate one more filtered graph using already generated filtered graph and by doing this compiler is throwing me some error while compiling. So I want to convert the filtered graph into regular graph and check how it behaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `boost::copy_graph` function that you can pass your filtered graph and a new `adjacency_list` and have it do the copy.

Comment: Hello Jeremiah, Thanks I tried it. I am using bundled edge properties, seems like it has some problem with bundled properties. I am getting runtime error saying vertex out of range. Any idea that you suggest?

Comment: @user1088211: Do you have a small program that has that problem?

Comment: Hello Jeremiah!! Directly I couldn't copy filtered graph to the original graph. So tried using a temporary graph which is of the same Graph type and for this copy_graph worked fine and later assigned this temporary graph to my required graph. So, the problem got solved and everything seems to be working fine. But I don't know why it was not copying directly. However, the problem is resolved and copy_graph() is really very useful indeed. Thanks for this suggestion. :)

Comment: Hello Jeremiah, I am not sure why I cant access the graph children when I use filtered graph.
For Instance: FilteredGraph fg(g1,er,keep_all()); //g1 is my original graph and wr is my predicate.
Graph test;
copy_graph(fg,test);
Graph::children_iterator c1,c2;
tie(c1,c2)= test.children();
Graph temp_graph1 = *c1; // is throwing me runtime error. 
Please I need some help with this.

Comment: @user1088211: `filtered_graph` does not have the infrastructure that `subgraph` does to have trees of child graphs and such; it is a lot simpler.  If you need that functionality, you will need to use `subgraph`.